# Examples showing that Sobolev embedding is optimal for a bounded domain?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

The question concerns the Sobolev continuous injection $H^s \to L^p$ on a bounded $C^2$ domain $\Omega$. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality#Generalizations) for the details. Are there any examples of function $u$, showing that the critical value of $p$, given by
$$
p_c = \frac{2d}{d-2s},
$$
is optimal? i.e. we cannot have continuous embedding for larger values of $p$.

On $\mathbb R^n$, it is very easy to find an example: just consider the dilation group, and show that we can keep the $H^s$ norm the same whilst pushing $L^p$ norm to $\infty$. However, such a non-compact, unbounded group is not that easily available for a bounded domain.